# Build CI pipeline using Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, continuous-integration, devops

I tried to build react application and got this error while building the Azure pipeline when I build it using azure DevOps.

[error image of the Azure pipeline in Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzDXT.png)

You can see the azure-pipeline.yml file code in my GitHub repository below.

[azure-pipeline.yml file code in GitHub repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Hun.png)

Comment: Check if package.json is committed to git server.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful `commit` of all changes in GitHub repository. Connected with azure continuous deployment I am not find any build related issues.

[image]

[image]
Try to `recommit` your recent edited files and `rebuild` once. To fix the issue.